# How to add a QWidget to a QMenuBar?

Tags: qt, qmenubar

I want to add a QLabel to a QMenuBar. I was able to add a QLabel to a QMenu using QActionWidget, but I want the QLabel to sit on the QMenuBar (as a substitute for a QMenu) at the right end of my application. I intend to add a movie to this QLabel in order to simulate a loading circle to indicate that the application is running. How can I add a QWidget to a QMenuBar, or is there some alternative to my ultimate goal? I am using Qt 5.6 with Qt Designer

Comment: This isn't portable, so it's best avoided. It'll look out of place on pretty much every environment Qt runs in.

Comment: Does the `QLabel` absolutely *have* to be part of the `QMenuBar`?  If not then why not add the `QMenuBar` and `QLabel` to the same `QHBoxLayout` with a 'stretch' in between.  Or perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: No the QLabel does not have to be a part of the QMenuBar. I would like to have it in the upper right corner of my application at all times. I can't seem to add the QMenuBar and QLabel to a QHBoxLayout. Is it even possible? I'm doing it in Qt Designer rather than programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A widget can be added to the end of the menu-bar with [QMenuBar::setCornerWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#setCornerWidget).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I was able to change the size of the QMovie with QMovie::setScaledSize