# Add a QMenuBar to a QWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, qwidget, pyside2, qmenubar

I'm trying to integrate a QMenubar in a QWidget in Pyside2 in Python3. It seems to be easier to integrate a QMenubar to a QMainWindow but I started the project with a QWidget and not a QMainWindow and this is why I would like to have a solution for a QWidget.

When I run the code, there is no error message but the menubar doesn't appear when I run the app. I checked that [stackoveflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832699/how-to-add-a-qwidget-to-a-qmenubar) but it didn't help me or I wasn't able to implement it.

**Code**

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QGraphicsView, 
QGridLayout)
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtOpenGL import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

image_path_str='image.jpg'

class View(QGraphicsView):
    photo_clicked = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(View, self).__init__()
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.scene.addItem(self.photo)
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image_path_str)
        self.photo.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.view = View(self)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.checkbox_P1= QtWidgets.QCheckBox("P1",self)
        self.line_edit_P1_x = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P1_x.setReadOnly(True)
        self.line_edit_P1_y = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P1_y.setReadOnly(True)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()
        self.archive = self.menubar.addMenu("archive")
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addWidget(self.checkbox_P1, 0, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P1_x, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P1_y, 2, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addLayout(self.grid_layout_P1_x_y, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.checkbox_P2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("P2",self)
        self.line_edit_P2_x = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P2_x.setReadOnly(True)
        self.line_edit_P2_y = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P2_y.setReadOnly(True)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addWidget(self.checkbox_P2, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P2_x, 0, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P2_y, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addLayout(self.grid_layout_P2_x_y, 1, 1, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.combo_box1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box1.addItem("measurements set 1")
        self.combo_box1.addItem("measurements set 1")

        self.combo_box2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box2.addItem("P1-P2")
        self.combo_box2.addItem("P3-P4")

        self.vertical1= QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.vertical1.addWidget(self.menubar)
        self.vertical1.addWidget(self.combo_box1)
        self.vertical1.addWidget(self.combo_box2)
        self.vertical1.addLayout(self.layout_contain_P1_P2)

        self.vertical2= QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vertical2.addWidget(self.view)

        self.horizontal= QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontal.addLayout(self.vertical1)
        self.horizontal.addLayout(self.vertical2)

        self.setLayout(self.horizontal)
        self.setWindowTitle("Image viewer")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 800)

app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
        app = QApplication([])
w = Window()
w.show()
w.raise_()
QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.CrossCursor))
app.exec_()
```

Here is screenshot of what I get:

[image]

**Edit : not optimal workaround: add a QMainWindow class**

Here is not optimal workaround. I had to add an extra `class` `QMainWindow` and call the `Widget` from within the `QMainWindow`

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QGraphicsView,
QGridLayout, QMainWindow, QAction, QMenu)
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide2.QtOpenGL import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

image_path_str='image.jpg'

class View(QGraphicsView):
    photo_clicked = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(View, self).__init__()
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.scene.addItem(self.photo)
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(image_path_str)
        self.photo.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.view = View(self)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.checkbox_P1= QtWidgets.QCheckBox("P1",self)
        self.line_edit_P1_x = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P1_x.setReadOnly(True)
        self.line_edit_P1_y = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P1_y.setReadOnly(True)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addWidget(self.checkbox_P1, 0, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P1_x, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P1_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P1_y, 2, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addLayout(self.grid_layout_P1_x_y, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.checkbox_P2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("P2",self)
        self.line_edit_P2_x = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P2_x.setReadOnly(True)
        self.line_edit_P2_y = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit_P2_y.setReadOnly(True)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addWidget(self.checkbox_P2, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P2_x, 0, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.grid_layout_P2_x_y.addWidget(self.line_edit_P2_y, 1, 0, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.layout_contain_P1_P2.addLayout(self.grid_layout_P2_x_y, 1, 1, Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.combo_box1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box1.addItem("measurements set 1")
        self.combo_box1.addItem("measurements set 1")

        self.combo_box2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box2.addItem("P1-P2")
        self.combo_box2.addItem("P3-P4")

        self.vertical1= QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        # self.vertical1.addWidget(self.menubar)
        self.vertical1.addWidget(self.combo_box1)
        self.vertical1.addWidget(self.combo_box2)
        self.vertical1.addLayout(self.layout_contain_P1_P2)

        self.vertical2= QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vertical2.addWidget(self.view)

        self.horizontal= QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontal.addLayout(self.vertical1)
        self.horizontal.addLayout(self.vertical2)

        self.setLayout(self.horizontal)
        self.setWindowTitle("Image viewer")
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1000, 800)

class Main_window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(Main_window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.window = Window()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.window)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('File')

        impMenu = QMenu('Import', self)
        impAct = QAction('Import mail', self)
        impMenu.addAction(impAct)

        newAct = QAction('New', self)

        fileMenu.addAction(newAct)
        fileMenu.addMenu(impMenu)


app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
        app = QApplication([])
mw = Main_window()
mw.show()
mw.raise_()
QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.CrossCursor))
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I see that the QMenuBar is present on the left side, in the following link there is a screenshoot of what I get: https://imgur.com/a/q8cwXHY

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @eyllanesc. I don't know what I'm run again the same code, and the menubar didn't appear. I also added a screenshot of what I got

Comment: @ecjb. If you're using Mac OSX, you probably need to read this: [QMenuBar as a Global Menu Bar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#qmenubar-as-a-global-menu-bar).

Comment: Thank you for the advice @ekhumoro, I'll read it and try to find a solution